# Using /MD library with /MDd application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I have a library i need to use in release mode since it's performance is reduced significantly without optimizations.
When i use it with /MD in my /MDd it gives crt warning, which i figure it is bad. (may cause heap corruption?)

so what i did is, keep all the release optimizations but link library with /MDd.
warning disappeared. 
however, could this cause any problems or performance loss?

Comment: Do you mean you need to use it in release even when you're building your application in debug?

Comment: yes. i debug a lot but that library has horrible debug build performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can cause performance loss to use /MDd instead of /MD, but this definitively depends on what you do. If you don't use the runtime in your performance-critical code anyway, you will not see any slow down.
Alternatively you could solve your problem the other way around: Build application and library with /MD, but the application still with debug information and without optimization.

Comment: slowdown is barely noticeable with /MDd. i can live with it since this is debug build.
 but would it cause runtime errors?

Comment: No, as long as you don't mix /MD and /MDd everything should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I learnt this the hard way. Spent 3 days debugging a heap corruption error thinking I was freeing something that was already freed, when in the end I think this is just it. I am yet to try it out. This isn't even my code entirely. Basically the application I am working on is built with code generation /MDd for debug builds while the client application that uses my application libraries is built with code generation /MD for debug builds. This started causing heap corruption errors all of a sudden. Will follow up if fixing this works. Thanks.